# Base change and restriction over Galois extenstion

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, invariant-theory

(Sorry for my bad English.)

Let $L/K$ be (if necessary finite) Galois extension, and $A$ be $K$-algebra.
Then the Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on $K$-algebra $A\otimes_K L$.

So by considering the invariant subring, we get $K$-algebra $(A\otimes_K L)^G\subset A\otimes_K L$.

Now I want if this sub$K$-algebra is isomorphic to $A$?

For example $A=K$ or polynomial ring over $K$ then it's true, but I don't know generally case.
Please help me hints, references.

Comment: Take a $K$-basis $\{x_i\}$ for $A$, so that every element in $A\otimes_KL$ can be written uniquely as a finite sum $\sum_ix_i\otimes\lambda_i$ with $\lambda_i$ in $L$. When is such an element fixed by every $g\in G$?

Comment: Thanks. Your comment helped me solve the problem.